# Need some alternate to move SOQL out of loop

Tags: trigger, visualforce-component

[image]I have a trigger which calls a Class. Below are the screenshots of the code.
[image]
When a Quote is created or updated then, Quote request date should be auto filled with Opp created date. Quote is a child of Opp. Condition is written in code.

My code is working fine but problem is i have written SOQL inside FOR loop which is tooo bad. I need some alternate solution for this. Please let me know how can i overcome this situation.

Comment: Post your code such a way that members can change taking from your question,  picture of your code is not helpful in this regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be,

1. Collect all quotes into a map by its id.
2. Get the list of quote ids and issue a single soql which fetches opportunity date by parent reference
3. Loop through soql response and for ecah quote, pick the quote object from step 1, and set the data object from result.

Give this a try and post if you are stuck at some step.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the below code.

```
public void PopulateDate(List<Quote_Information__c> quoteList)
{   
    Map<Id, DateTime> mapquoteDate = new Map<Id, DateTime>();
    List<id> oppId = new List<Id>();
    for(Quote_Information__c quoteObj : quoteList){
        oppId.add(quoteObj.Opportunity__c);
    }
    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT id, CreatedDate from Opportunity where Id in :oppId]);
    for(Quote_Information__c quoteObj : quoteList)
    {
        if((quoteObj.Quote_Type__c == 'First Quote') || (quoteObj.Quote_Type__c == 'Alternate Quote'))
        {
            quoteObj.Quote_Request_Date__c = oppMap.get(quoteObj.Opportunity__c).CreatedDate;
        }
    }
}
```

I have moved the SOQL out of FOR loop.

Hope this helps :)